# How to directly land on specific position without scrolling?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

How can I open specific position in listview? Let me tell what's my requirement and what I tried!
It's table of contents where when we are in page no 100, and when we click table of contents, it displays 100th page by highlighting. This is the requirment.
But in my case what's happening is, it keeps on scrolling and user needs to wait till the scrolling stops at 100th page. I used setSelection but it doesn't work.
So if I use smoothScrollingToPosition , it keeps on scrolling to stop at specific position. So my requirement is without scrolling directly to open specific page.
Below is the logic. I applied listview in constructor of the class Adapter.

In adapter,

```
@Override
    public final View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if ((convertView == null) || (((Integer) convertView.getTag()) != type)) {
            convertView = createView(position);
            convertView.setTag(type);
        }

        final BaseTableOfContents node = getItem(position);

        for(int i=0; i<mNodes.size();i++){
            BaseTableOfContents nodes = mNodes.get(i);
            if(okayToHighlightAnchorNode(nodes,i)==true){ //only when true, it lands to specific position. 
                Log.v("nodes","nodes"+okayToHighlightAnchorNode(nodes,i) + nodes.getText() + i);
             //   returnValue.getListView().setSelection(i); //but this is not working. 
                returnValue.getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(i,i); //this keeps on scrolling to specific page instead of directly landing to the specific page.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For a direct scroll use this below code:**

```
getListView().setSelection(21);// anylistview.setSelection(21);
```

**For a smooth scroll use this:**

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(21);//anylistview.smoothScrollToPosition(21);
```

Comment: Direct scroll not working. That's the problem. I already mentioned above.

Comment: `getListView().smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);` you may use this too

Comment: what is offset and duration?

Comment: `position` -> Position to scroll to
`offset` ---->Desired distance in pixels of position from the top of the view when scrolling is finished
`duration`-> Number of milliseconds to use for the scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
yourListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);
```

where `position` is where you want to scroll , `duration` is number of milliseconds taken to scroll, and `offset` is the distance in pixel

Comment: @star did you try this.